# Serilog log statement disappears after first log statement

Tags: azure, logging, azure-cosmosdb, serilog

I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1. Developed a logger component on top of Serilog and wanted to use Azure Document Db sink. I am getting a strange behavior. My first log statement appears in Document Db, but the subsequent log messages are not coming, upon an application restart.

```
    internal class SeriLogger : ILogger
    {

        private static readonly string EndpointUri = "https://mysample.documents.azure.com:443/";
        private static readonly string AuthKey = "UkgOMJT08bA5KOvd1O9IYgo0w==";
        private static readonly string DatabaseName = "Diagnostics";
        private static readonly string CollectionName = "Logs";

        protected readonly Serilog.Core.Logger logger;

        public SeriLogger()
        {
            logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.AzureDocumentDB(EndpointUri, AuthKey, DatabaseName, CollectionName)
                .CreateLogger();
            //logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            //.WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(
            //    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "log-{Date}.txt"), fileSizeLimitBytes: 536870912)
            //    .CreateLogger();
        }

public void Log(string message, LogLevelEnum logLevel)
        {
            switch (logLevel)
            {
                case LogLevelEnum.Debug: logger.Debug(message); break;
                case LogLevelEnum.Information: logger.Information(message); break;
                case LogLevelEnum.Warning: logger.Warning(message); break;
                case LogLevelEnum.Error: logger.Error(message); break;
                case LogLevelEnum.Fatal: logger.Fatal(message); break;
            }
        }
```

My first call to Log() method creates a new document, but this stops from second call on wards. If I restart the application, first call creates a log entry as a new document and not working afterwards. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Below are the Nuget versions I am using

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Serilog" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.AzureDocumentDb" version="3.5.18" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.File" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

But the logging works perfectly with Rolling File sink. Please help me.

I tried to enable diagnostics for serilog like below `Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));` 
Now I can see two lines in my VS output window.
2017-03-14T07:40:18.5291346Z Sending batch of 2 messages to DocumentDB
2017-03-14T07:40:22.1107764Z One or more errors occurred.

Comment: Make sure you dispose `logger` when the app shuts down - batched events might need to be flushed through.

Comment: Hello, I tried to dispose after a usage. But the log messages are not even reaching Document Db(not even first time). I am using .NET 4.6.1 and will that be a cause?

Comment: I tried to enable diagnostics for serilog like below Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg)); Now I can see two lines in my VS output window 2017-03-14T07:40:18.5291346Z                                                 Sending batch of 2 messages to DocumentDB
2017-03-14T07:40:22.1107764Z One or more errors occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I test it base on your code, there is no document created to log message in the document db.
But if  I add `WriteTo.Console()`, then it works correctly. Please have a try to use following code.

```
logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console()
             .WriteTo.AzureDocumentDB(EndpointUri, AuthKey, DatabaseName, CollectionName)
                 .CreateLogger();
```

The following is my detail steps.

1. Create a console application with .net framework 4.6.1
2. Add a class named `SeriLogger`

[image]

3. Add the test code in the pramgram.cs

[image]

4. Check the result from the console and in the Azure portal

[image]

packages.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Serilog" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.AzureDocumentDb" version="3.5.18" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.Console" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Hi Tom, I tried the same. But issue persists. Looks like I observed the pattern. If the collection is empty it will create the first log message and nothing gets created there after. If you empty the collection, it will again create the first document and stops there after.

Comment: In my side, I can't repro the issue that you mentioned. But nothing will be created if I don't add the code `.WriteTo.Console()`. I will update the answer with my detail steps. Hope it is useful.

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT the error being produced in the output window by Serilog's `SelfLog` is: `2017-03-14T07:40:22.1107764Z One or more errors occurred.` (See comments on question post.) Any clue from that? Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Tom and Nicholas for your inputs. I am yet to figure out what is wrong in my code/environment. I even hosted in Azure as a Web App, but the issue persists. I am thinking about leaving Serilog and go ahead with log4net. There is a blog post about having an appender for Doc DB http://korrozia.blogspot.in/2016/11/how-to-store-log4net-messages-to-azure.html. Hope it will work. Any comments are most welcome

Comment: Hey, Its an issue with sink looks like. I opened an issue https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-azuredocumentdb/issues/48. I have a generic question. Can I use this sinks for a production. Are they stable enough?